# Equivalence of the Goldbach conjecture with Goldbach's original conjecture.

Tags: number-theory

In Goldbach's time, 1 was considered to be a prime number. Correct me if I misunderstand, but I am told  Goldbach's original conjecture was that every even number greater than or equal or 2 is the sum of two prime* numbers, where prime* means prime or 1. The conjecture nowadays is recast as "every even number greater than or equal to 4 is the sum of two prime numbers". Have these formulations been proven equivalent? One direction of the equivalence is easy, but what about the other?

Comment: This information appears on the Wikipedia page. No, they are not known to be equivalent. There could be an even number $N = p+1$ that is not a sum of two primes (if the modern version of the conjecture is not true).

Comment: The first sentence [isn't quite right](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2007), history is more complicated.